# Why is my printf formatting not working with GCC but is running on Windows

Tags: c, linux, gcc

We just did a lesson of C on pointers and I had trouble running the example code on my linux machine (Mint 17 64 bit) though it's running fine on Windows 7 (32 bit). The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int var = 20; //actual variable declaration
        int *ip; //pointer declaration

        ip = &var; //store address of var in pointer

        printf("Address of var variable: %x\n", &var);

        //address stored in pointer variable
        printf("Address stored in ip variable: %x\n", ip);

        //access the value using the pointer
        printf("Value of *ip variable: %d\n", *ip);

        return 0;
}
```

The program runs as expected on windows with the code blocks ide, but on linux trying to compile in the terminal using GCC I get the following error:

```
pointers.c: In function ‘main’:
pointers.c:9:2: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but   argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("Address of var variable: %x\n", &var);
  ^
pointers.c:12:2: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("Address stored in ip variable: %x\n", ip);
  ^
```

I'd like to know what's going on and how I can get the code to run on linux.

Comment: You don't get *errors*, you get *warnings*.  GCC is telling you that you might have written something you didn't intend.  Since you are deliberately intending to see the numeric value of a pointer (on a machine where pointers have numeric values), you can go ahead and run the program.

Comment: It's refusing to compile because there's no a.out file or any option for me to continue regardless of the warnings.

Answer (score 6):

The `%x` format specifier requires `unsigned int` value, otherwise it's undefined behaviour (so anything could happen, you can't be sure what it does on any other compiler or maybe different moon phase). According to latest C99 draft, `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function* p.8, 9 (emphasis mine)

> `o,u,x,X` The **`unsigned int`** argument is converted to unsigned octal (`o`),
>   unsigned decimal (`u`), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (**`x`** or **`X`**)
>
> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the **behavior is undefined**.

Note that for pointers you should use `%p` format specifer rather than `%x` or `%d`, e.g.:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) ip);
```

Comment: Don't we have c11 now?

Comment: You are right that C11 is current C standard, but it's not adopted widely yet, is there any difference ?

Comment: Those excerpts are the same.

Comment: Thanks, but even when I change the declaration to unsigned int I'm still getting an error with the compiler saying:

    format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("Address stored in ip variable: %x\n", ip);

Comment: @chmod777: For pointers (i.e. to see address that this pointer holds) you should use `%p` format specifier, that is intended for them, e.g. `printf("%p\n", (void *) ip);`